# Redirection from observer not working (Fullpage Cache + APC turned on)

Tags: event-observer, redirect, 301-redirect

I am trying to redirect to custom url if certain url is matched using event: `controller_action_predispatch`

a> Registering event: controller_action_predispatch

```
<frontend>
    <events>
        <controller_action_predispatch>
            <observers>
                <redirect_controller_action_predispatch>
                    <class>redirect/observer</class>
                    <method>controllerActionPredispatch</method>
                </redirect_controller_action_predispatch>
            </observers>
        </controller_action_predispatch>
    </events>
</frontend>
```

b> Implementing the observer model

```
<?php
class MagePsycho_Redirect_Model_Observer
{
    public function controllerActionPredispatch(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
    {
        $action         = $observer->getControllerAction();
        $request        = $action->getRequest();
        $requestUrl     = isset($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']) ? $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] : $request->getRequestUri();

        if (stripos($requestUrl, '/' . 'old-404-url-key') !== false) {
            $redirectUrl = Mage::getUrl('new-url-key');
            Mage::log('redirect-matched::' . $redirectUrl);
            $action->getResponse()->setRedirect($redirectUrl, 301);
            $action->getRequest()->setDispatched(true);
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

Above code works fine in localhost but not on live server where Full Page Cache + APC caching is turned on (Magento EE 1.13).

What am I missing, anything needs to be checked in case of Full Page Cache + APC turned on?

Any help is appreciated.

[EDIT]
The redirection issue is only for 404 error. If i try to redirect some non existing page (i.e. 404 page) to some valid page, the redirection doesn't work.

Comment: With Varnish this observer will never get fired one page is cached. Also curious how did you combined FPC and Varnish.

Comment: @Tim it's APC, i edited my title :). Yeah it seems 404 error (cms_index_noRoute) is cached and there is no redirection thereafter even the code is called. How to fix, any idea? like bypass caching for cms_index_noRoute, something like that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sometimes a simple PHP solution works too, don't always think in #Magento way ;)

Replaced this piece of code:

```
$action->getResponse()->setRedirect($redirectUrl, 301);
$action->getRequest()->setDispatched(true);
```

by:

```
@header("HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently");
@header("Location: " . $redirectUrl);
exit();
```

But still if someone knows how to make it work in a Magento way, I would re-consider the accepted answer.

Comment: whenever you Redirect from observer, you need to put an `exit()`; OR `$observer->getRequest()->setParam('return_url','http://www.google.com/');`

Comment: I had used return statement though.

Comment: But is `@header("Location: " . $redirectUrl);
exit();` recommended ?

Answer (score 2):

As per our discussion in the IRC, use webserver redirects.

Your goal is to redirect old urls to new urls. This is the job of the webserver, not the application. Otherwise you are loading the application twice for each of these requests.

Comment: We are using nginx server, what would be the best approach for massive 301 redirects?

Comment: Check out the map module: http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_map_module.html That should point you in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

i have find another solution which is working  and it forward url to anthor page.

1. `First  current get request url object. $request=Mage::app()->getRequest();`
2. Now not dispatch current urt using  set `->setDispatched()` function  value to false.

code

```
$request->setDispatched(false);
```

3. add a  `new parameter  forwarded=true to   request  parameter using`

   ->`setParam('forwarded', true)` **Which forward to new url**

code is:

```
$request->setParam('forwarded', true)
```

**4.** now set `new forwarded url using set routename ,controller and action` and code is like

```
$request
->setRouteName($routername)
->setControllerName($controllername)
->setActionName($actionname)
```

Example: i write all contacts page to index page:

```
    $request=Mage::app()->getRequest();
$request->setParam('forwarded', true)
                        ->setRouteName('cms')
                        ->setControllerName('index')
                        ->setActionName('index')
                         ->setDispatched(false);
```

Edit: for ajax request try this

```
  if ($request->getParam('isIframe')) {
                    $request->setParam('forwarded', true)
            ->setRouteName($routername)
                        ->setControllerName($controllername)
                        ->setActionName($actionname)
                        ->setDispatched(false);
                } elseif($request->getParam('isAjax')) {
                    $request->setParam('forwarded', true)
                        ->setControllerName($controllername)
            ->setRouteName($routername)
                        ->setActionName($actionname)
                        ->setDispatched(false);
                } else {
                    $request->setParam('forwarded', true)
                        ->setRouteName($routername)
                        ->setControllerName($controllername)
                        ->setActionName('login')
                        ->setDispatched(false);
                }
```